# Typescript: Generic Type being inferred to Literal Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Having an issue where "`f<T>(val:T) {}; f(5);`" is causing T to be a Literal Type of 5 instead of Number. Can I specify that I do not want a literal type here, as I want T to be a number (or any non literal) in this case?

Comment: What's your use case here? It seems to me that the TS compiler is doing what it's supposed to -- with a constant value of `5` being passed to `f`, the type is indeed the literal `5` and cannot be anything else (whereas if you pass a variable of type number into it that has a runtime-determined value, it will just be a number). If you want the type to be number, why not change `T` to `number` or `T extends number` ?

Comment: How wide do you want `T` do be?  If I have `declare const x: { a: 0, b: "", c: true}` and call `f(x)` do you want `T` to be `{a: number, b: string, c: boolean}`?  --- What about `function cb(p: "yes" | "no") {}; f(cb);`?  Do you want `T` to be `(p: "yes" | "no")=>void` or `(p: never)=>void`?  (Note that `(p: string)=>void` is not valid, since `cb` does not accept `string` arguments in general... `cb("oops")` is an error)

Comment: @jcalz I see your point, I think this answers my question.. I need I need to change my overall approach.

Answer (score 0):

`extends number` will do that for you, but also will block any number types

```
let f1 = <T extends number>(val: T) => val;
let result1 = f1(5); // 5
let result2 = f1(true) // Error
```

But adding map number into 5 will works for any type

```
let f2 = <T>(val: T) => val;
let result1 = f2(5 as 5) // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem is I want T to be any type except literals. However, this might be the closest thing otherwise.